# Declaring initialized C++ static variable (syntax disambiguation)

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, c++03

Suppose I have the following C++11 code:

```
template<typename T>
const T& GetValueOrDefault(T* pPtr) const
{
    static const T oDefaultInstance {};     // MSVC error here.
    return pPtr ? *pPtr : oDefaultInstance;
}
```

The problem that I face is that it is not valid in MSVC 2012: MSVC 2012 doesn't support uniform initialization syntax.

To ensure that you fully understand my intentions I provide the this behavior description of the line where the error occurs:

1. If `T` is of object type the default constructor is called.

   1.1. If `T` is a class then the variable should be constructed in-place, i.e. the statement should support non-movable and/or non-copyable classes (not relying on RVO).
2. If `T` is of scalar type the default value (zero) is used on initialization.

Such kind of behavior could be archived with the next line if I force the compiler to interpret it as a variable definition with initialization:

```
static const T oDefaultInstance();
```

My question is: how to write the line above to force the correct (for me) parse in C++2003 (or at least in MSVC 2012) ?

Comment: static variables are already zero-initialized followed by default-initialization without any parenthesis at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seeams, this simple solution is the one you want:

```
template<typename T>
const T& GetValueOrDefault(T* pPtr) const
{
    static T oDefaultInstance;
    return pPtr ? *pPtr : oDefaultInstance;
}
```

Static native variable are zero-initialized, else, the default constructor is called.

For your point abour RVO, perhaps I missed something. I don't see why your default instance should be copied, as you return a reference.

Comment: The point about RVO was to forbid the following: 
static const T oDefaultInstance = T();